# How to maintain Multiple log4j.xml configuration file

Tags: java, xml, log4j

How to maintain multiple log4j.xml configuration files in one webapplication.

Eg:- **In Servlet:-**

```
 public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
       PropertyConfigurator.configure("/home/madhavib/Desktop/Nar/Raju/log4j.properties");
 }
```

**In Jsp:-**

```
 public void jspInit() {

      DOMConfigurator.configure("/home/madhavib/Desktop/Nar/log4j.xml"); 
}
```

**In another Jsp:-**

```
public void jspInit() {

     DOMConfigurator.configure("/home/madhavib/Desktop/Nar/log4j.xml"); 
}




**log4j configuration files (loaded in jsp 1):** 

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

 <appender name="FileAppender"
  class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" >
  <!-- <param name="threshold" value="debug" /> -->
  <param name="File" value="/home/madhavib/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/logs/EntelProject/infojsp333.log" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="%d %-5p [%t] %c{5}- %m%n" />
  </layout>
   <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="debug" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="warn" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
  <!-- <MarkerFilter marker="FLOW" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/> -->
 </appender>




<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" 
    value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
     </layout>
</appender>



 <logger name="org.apache.jsp">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</logger> 
 <!--<root>

  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</root> -->
  <logger name="pe1.com1.nextel1">
   <level value="info"/>
<appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>


</logger> 

</log4j:configuration>

**log4j confuguration (loaded in jsp 2) :-**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

 <appender name="FileAppender"
  class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" >
  <!-- <param name="threshold" value="debug" /> -->
  <param name="File" value="/home/madhavib/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/logs/EntelProject/examplejsp.log" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="%d %-5p [%t] %c{5}- %m%n" />
  </layout>
   <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="debug" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="warn" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
  <!-- <MarkerFilter marker="FLOW" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/> -->
 </appender>




<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" 
    value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
     </layout>
</appender>



 <logger name="org.apache.jsp">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</logger> 

  <logger name="pe.com.nextel">
   <level value="info"/>
<appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>


</logger> 

</log4j:configuration>

**log4jconfiguration file(loaded in servlet) :-**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

 <appender name="FileAppender"
  class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" >
  <!-- <param name="threshold" value="debug" /> -->
  <param name="File" value="/home/madhavib/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/logs/EntelProject/examplejsp.log" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="%d %-5p [%t] %c{5}- %m%n" />
  </layout>
   <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="debug" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="warn" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
  <!-- <MarkerFilter marker="FLOW" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/> -->
 </appender>




<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" 
    value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
     </layout>
</appender>



 <logger name="org.apache.jsp">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</logger> 

  <logger name="pe.com.nextel">
   <level value="info"/>
<appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>


</logger> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

How to maintain multiple log4j.xml configuration files in one webapplication.

i have given log4j configuration information files , please look into that and tell me the how to proper develop with multiple log4j files.

Comment: Can you explain, why you feel the need to do that?

Comment: Yes obviously you can do it, its a matter of loading log4j.xml file which should not change the behavior of other logging. But the question is why you will do that?

Comment: i want to maintain log4j for jsp as well java seperatly but when i load in servlet init method it working but after loading in jsp init method the log4j.xml is overriding by current log4j.xml.

but the problem is when we go to servlet the loaded log4j file in servlet is not working

Comment: And why do you need different logging configurations for JSP and the servlet?

Comment: in my application i am using webservice as well as jsp pages and when request is comes from webservice only java related logs should be generate and when request is from jsp both jsp page and that related java files logger should be genereate

Comment: please reply to my question if there is any solution and please suggest me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to specify different Loggers then but in one config file. You can configure that other Logger with different appenders, then. Have a close look into the log4j configuration docs. For us to help you further, you could append the contents of your configs to your question.

Comment: i want to load multiple lo4j.xml files at a time and those  log4j.xml files use according to the application flow. for that i am servlet init method and jsp init methods

Comment: Yes, we understood that. But that's not how it's done. Please add the configs, so we can advise.

Comment: i have added log4j configuration files above, please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple log4j configuration files in some ways:

1. You can set System properties :

   System.setProperty("log4j2.configurationFile", "log4j2-1.xml,log4j2-2.xml");
2. You can put configuration files as "log4j2.component.properties" under resource section and define system property as follows :

   log4j2.configurationFile=log4j2-1.xml,log4j2-2.xml

Please check [official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) for system properties